# C# Best way to find the middle character(s) of a string

Tags: c#, string

What is the best way to find the middle character or characters of a string using C#

I know I could count how many characters are in the string then work out which index or indexs to get, but is there a better way, faster way, maybe regEx, something built in to C#

So if the input was "car" the output would be "a" but if the input was cars the out put would be "ar"

Comment: `var middleChar = myString[myString.Length / 2];` Going to be hard to beat the performance of integer division + indexed array lookup.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What went wrong with the code you have so far? Can you please add those details? As it stands, this is a request for code and isn't a question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I imagine the reason has to do with the fact that questions such as "What is the best way..." are difficult to answer definitely.  I can also say that I can't imagine regEx would be faster even if there was a feature in it for this, which I doubt.

Comment: What is the middle char in a string with an even number of chars?

Comment: @ John Wu That is a bit oversimplified, no? I have very little experience with C#. Can you really just take the index of a string like that? I thought C# was strongly / statically typed...

Comment: @NathanToulbert Classes can implement [indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers), which the string class does ([source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs)). It also implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can treat a `string` just like a collection of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We first need to determine if the string has an even or odd number of characters.

If there's an odd number of characters, we take the integer division of `Length / 2`, and then take `1` character from that position.

But if there's an *even* number of characters, then we have to subtract `1` from the integer division of `Length / 2`, and we want to take `2` characters from that position.

In code we can use the modulus operator (`%`) to determine if the `Length` is even, and set an `offset` variable to the appropriate value (`1` for even, `0` for odd), and then use that to get the start position and length of substring to take:

```
var offset = input.Length % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0; 
var middle = input.Substring(input.Length / 2 - offset, offset + 1);
```

Comment: Ideally that could work, but there is a problem in adding 'Offset+1' , I tried your code and one more example ; it prints 2 characters if 'OffSet' value is 1


` public void MiddleOfStringSubString(string data)
    { 
        int length = data.Length;
        var mod = length % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        int mid = length / 2 - mod;
        var midChar = data.Substring(mid, mod+1);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Data is {data} , length = {length} , middle = {mid}  mod = {mod} || Result = {midChar}");
    } `

Comment: Try below datasets and you get the following .

Data is ab , length = 2 , middle = 0  mod = 1 || Result = ab
Data is abc , length = 3 , middle = 1  mod = 0 || Result = b
Data is abcd , length = 4 , middle = 1  mod = 1 || Result = bc
Data is abcde , length = 5 , middle = 2  mod = 0 || Result = c
Data is abcdef , length = 6 , middle = 2  mod = 1 || Result = cd

Comment: @jidh I don't understand the problem you're trying to point out. The original question specified that they *want* to output 2 characters if the length of the input string is even: *"if the input was **cars** the output would be "**ar**""*. If you want to output only a single character for odd strings, then you'd have to state an additional rule that specifies how to determine which one to return.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
string myString = "yourtexthere";
if(myString.Length % 2 == 0){
    Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring((myString.Length / 2 ) - 1, 2));
}else{
    Console.WriteLine(myString[myString.Length / 2]);
}
```

Although I'm sure there's a prettier way to do this.